# Difference between find and filter

Tags: javascript

I have recently jumped into the world of jQuery. I saw the methods `find()` and `filter()` but can not figure out the difference between the two.

What exactly is the difference between the two?

Comment: Find also stops after the first found match whereas filter returns all the matches.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) reduces the set of already matched elements, while [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) gets descendants of the matched element.

Comment: What is a descendent of an element? And more importantly, why is it required information to understand the answer? Please consider improving this answer with an explanation of the terms used.

Answer (score 70):

Find vs Filter

Let's say you have this array:

```
var folks = [ 
  {name: "Bob", age: "32", occupation: "developer"}, 
  {name: "Bill", age: "17", occupation: "delinquent"}, 
  {name: "Brad", age: "40", occupation: "yes"} 
]
```

**Find**:

```
folks.find( fella => fella.name === "Bob")
//Returns an object: {name: "Bob", age: "32", occupation: "developer"}
```

**Filter**:

```
folks.filter( fella => fella.name === "Bob")
//Returns an array: [ {name: "Bob", age: "32", occupation: "developer"} ]
```

Comment: allow me to have a question deriving out of it
what difference will this make: folks.find( fella => name.indexOf("Bob") > -1)
i know indexOf searches element's index in the string and is generally used to search the substring. But i want to know the performance difference between triple equal and indexOf

Comment: if search fails, `find` will returns `undefined` while filter will returns an empty array `[]`

Comment: Find returns the matching object, and filter returns an array containing matching objects. It is very common to have an array of objects in a data pattern.  Usually when I use find, I'm looking for it using ID or something that is unique.  Usually when I use filter, I'm trying to narrow down something, using search words, etc.

Answer (score 54):

.find() will look and stop after the first match, whereas, .filter() will continue searching through the entire array

Comment: find return 'undefined' if nothing is matched
filter return [ ] if nothing is matched

Answer (score 12):

While looking for answers to the question, I found a [nice blog](https://mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-filter-and-find-in-jquery/) explaining the same.
[Mkyong](https://mkyong.com/author/mkyong/) writes:

> Both filter() and find() methods are very similar, except the former is applies to all the elements, while latter searches child elements only.
>
> - filter() – search through all the elements.
> - find() – search through all the child elements only.

Try his demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filterClick").click(function() {
    $('div').css('background', 'white');
    $('div').filter('#Fruits').css('background', 'red');
  });

  $("#findClick").click(function() {
    $('div').css('background', 'white');
    $('div').find('#Fruits').css('background', 'red');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>jQuery find() vs filter() example</h1>
<div id="Fruits">
  Fruits
  <div id="Apple">Apple</div>
  <div id="Banana">Banana</div>
</div>
<div id="Category">
  Category
  <div id="Fruits">Fruits</div>
  <div id="Animals">Animals</div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<input type='button' value='filter(Fruits)' id='filterClick'>
<input type='button' value='find(Fruits)' id='findClick'>
```

View on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhatkrishnakishor/WXZ8m/)

Answer (score 8):

**find()**

`find()` returns the descendants of the selected elements that match the selector.

From the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector.

**filter()**

`filter()` filters the elements based on the selector or the provided function.

From the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Answer (score 7):

Consider you have an array of objects with **duplicate** values for the **'id'** and see below the result for the **find** and **filter** methods.

```
let arrObj = [  { id:1, name:"One" },
                { id:2, name:"Two" },
                { id:1, name:"One" }
            ];

var resultObj    = arrObj.find(v => v.id === 1);    // { id: 1, name: 'One'}

var resultArrObj = arrObj.filter(v => v.id === 1);  // [ 
                                                    //   { id:1, name:"One" },
                                                    //   { id:1, name:"One" }
                                                    // ]
```

`find`:

1. **Stops** further iteration once the condition is true.
2. return **'undefined'** if nothing is matched

`filter`:

1. Iterate **all** the items in the array.
2. **Always** return an array.

Answer (score 5):

`find()` returns children of the match elements for the given selector, `filter()` looks at the matched elements and returns the ones that *also* match the given selector.

Answer (score 3):

`find()` and `filter()` both methods work with array

```
    let customers = [{
        name: 'ABC Inc',
        credit: 100
    }, {
        name: 'ACME Corp',
        credit: 200
    }, {
        name: 'IoT AG',
        credit: 300
    }];
```

What is `find()`?
`find()` method return the first value which match from the collection. `find()` method search the array from the start if the desired value is matched then `find()` method return that value and terminate and rest of the array is not process.

```
    let findCustomers = customers.find(customer=>{
    return customer.credit<300
    })
    
    console.log(findCustomers)
    
    /// [{
       name: 'ABC Inc',
        credit: 100
    }];
```

What is `filter()`?
`filter()` method returns the match value from the array. it search whole array from start to end and returns all the value which is matched.

```
    let findCustomers = customers.flter(customer=>{
    return customer.credit<300
    })
    
    console.log(findCustomers)
    
    /// [{
    name: 'ABC Inc',
    credit: 100
    }, {
    name: 'ACME Corp',
    credit: 200
    }];
```

Answer (score 2):

filter gives the array and the data found but find only gives the data in array not the array

Comment: You do not add any value in addition to the previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

The filter() method is used to filters all the elements and returns the element that matches and the element that do not match are removed.

The only difference is the filter() method search through all the elements while find() method search through all the child elements only.

Answer (score 1):

find:

1. return first item with matching condition
2. return an object or value
3. return undefined if nothing matched

filter:

1. return all matching items
2. return an array (always)
3. return blank array e.g. [], if nothing matched

Let's see some examples:

```
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];
**// find**
const found = array1.find(x => x > 10);  
// Return 12

**//filter**
const found = array1.filter(element => element > 10);
// Return [12, 130, 44]
```

Let's see some example of object array:

```
let person = [ 
  { name: "Bob", age: "32", occupation: "developer" }, 
  { name: "Bill", age: "17", occupation: "delinquent" }, 
  { name: "Brad", age: "40", occupation: "yes" } 
];

const found = person.find(item => item.age > 30);
// return { name: "Bob", age: "32", occupation: "developer" }

const found = person.filter(item => item.age > 30);
/* return [
  { name: "Bob", age: "32", occupation: "developer" }, 
  { name: "Brad", age: "40", occupation: "yes" }
] */
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more a javascript question then jQuery.

find: **returns underfined if not found** otherwise returns the found element.

filter: **will always return an array** that contains the found elements or an empty array.

both functions find and filter can be used to find through all child elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Difference between find and filter**

1. **filter()** method search through all the elements.
2. **find(**) method search through all the child elements only.