# Templates with out root level nodes

Tags: jquery, html, coding-style, templating

I have been experimenting with templating in js and have come across a pretty cool problem.  Say you have a handlebars template. Then compile it and output it

```
var template =
  '<h1>Hello</h1>' +
  '<ul>' +
    '<li>{{name}}</li>' +
    '<li>{{address}}</li>' +
    '<li>{{phone}}</li>' +
  '</ul>';

var html = Handbars.compile(template)(
  {name: 'Austin', address: '42nd St.' phone: '(123) 456-7890'}
);

// Results in
console.log(html);
=> <h1>Hello</h1>
   <ul>
     <li>Austin</li>
     <li>42nd St.</li>
     <li>(123) 456-7890</li>
   </ul>
```

Now say you want to make that a jQuery object and act on it maybe find the ul

```
var $html = $(html)
var x = $html.find('ul');  \\ Or
var y = $('ul', $html)

console.log(x);
=> []

conosle.log(y);
=> 

console.log($html)
=> [<h1>Hello</h1>, <ul>...</ul>]
```

What this shows is when you jQueryify a string without a root node you get an array of nodes

and the finds only act on `$html[0]`

The only way I have been able to solve this is to include a root node in my templates but I don't like adding pointless non-semantic markup just because jQuery will not act nice.

How can you solve this programmatically instead of modifying markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, `.find` *does* operate on both elements of the jQuery object, but it only `find`s their descendants. What you want is `.filter`:

```
var x = $html.filter('ul');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user:

```
$html.filter('ul');
```

**Keynote:**

- filter will select a certain subset (zero or more) of the already
  selected elements.
- find will select a set of (zero or more) elements that are descendants
  of the already selected elements.

You can also check [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378757/difference-between-find-and-filter-in-jquery)