# Why do I get undefined when trying to get a dynamically added data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get the value for data-tab-id based on the class .tab-btn.active | however, the result keeps returning undefined.

This is where I add the data attribute

```
$navigation.find(".tab-btn").each(function(i, ele) {
        $(ele).attr("data-tab-id", i);
    });
```

This is where I retrieve it

```
var autoSwitch = setInterval(function() {

    //Get maximum # of tabs
    maxTabs = $(".tab-btn").length;
                        
    //Get the currently active button
    pastActiveBtn = $(".tab-btn").find(".active");
    pastId = pastActiveBtn.data('tabId'); //I have also tried tab-id; also 'undefined'

    console.log(pastId); //OUTPUT = undefined

});
```

If anyone knows why I am getting this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Try `pastActiveBtn = $(".tab-btn").filter(".active");`. Filter will look at the currently matched element, while find will look at the decendents

Comment: Honestly if you're using jQuery, the "natural" way to do things is to let the library manage your "data" stuff. Don't set the attribute, but use the `.data()` API to set values. It's done independently of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using
`pastActiveBtn = $(".tab-btn").filter(".active");`
Filter will look at the currently matched element, while find will look at the descendants.
More details about the difference between `filter` and `find` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10378800/10377254) answer.