# How JQuery select elements under the hood?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, internals

I was wondering how jquery really works internally. For example I want to know how jquery selectors works under the hood ? Does it loop through all DOM elements ? Or it has another magic algorithm for finding elements ?

And how does it differs from .find() and .filter() functions ?

Do you guys have any idea ?

Comment: Use this to make browsing jquery's source easier: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/

Comment: Use the source https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Comment: Regarding .find() and .filter(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438223/jquery-confusion-in-figuring-out-the-difference-between-find-and-filter

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses pretty much the same principles as browsers themselves when they need to apply style rules from elements - scan all elements and check against all rules declared in CSS.

And so does jquery:

```
for each element in given subtree/input set do
  if element matches selector do 
     add element to output set
  end if
end for
return output set
```

So the task has computational complexity of `O(N)`
where N is a number of DOM elements in input set.

There are quite few tricks/optimizations possible but in general 
it is as complex as that.

Some jQuery selectors have even worse complexity, for example this 
`$( "li:has(ul)")` selector has computation complexity of `O(N*N)`
so use with care.